# AWS::Serverless::HttpApi Minimum TLS version

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless, aws-http-api

As the Title Suggest , I would like to ask if there's a way to set minimum version of TLS1.2 for AWS::Serverless::HttpApi ?

Comment: Did you see that: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-custom-domain-tls-version.html

Comment: Hi @Peter Thank you for replying the link you refered was for Rest Api . im working on Http Api. But i did found my answer.